# Не выполнять анимацию когда пользователь открывает страницу

Tags: css3, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

```js
  c.onclick = e => document.querySelector('.setti').classList.toggle('ani');
```

```css
 svg { width: 100px }
path {transform-origin: 18px 18px; animation: cog1 100ms forwards linear}
.ani path {animation: cog 100ms forwards linear}
@keyframes cog1 {0% {transform:rotate(60deg)} 100% {transform:rotate(0deg)}}
@keyframes cog {0% {transform:rotate(0deg)} 100% {transform:rotate(60deg)}}
rect {fill:#ff0000; width:13px; height:9px;}
text {fill: white; font-size: 7px}
```

```html
<div id='c'>КЛИК</div>
<svg class='setti' viewBox="0 0 36 36">
  <path d="m 23.94,18.78 c .03,-0.25 .05,-0.51 .05,-0.78 0,-0.27 -0.02,-0.52 -0.05,-0.78 l 1.68,-1.32 c .15,-0.12 .19,-0.33 .09,-0.51 l -1.6,-2.76 c -0.09,-0.17 -0.31,-0.24 -0.48,-0.17 l -1.99,.8 c -0.41,-0.32 -0.86,-0.58 -1.35,-0.78 l -0.30,-2.12 c -0.02,-0.19 -0.19,-0.33 -0.39,-0.33 l -3.2,0 c -0.2,0 -0.36,.14 -0.39,.33 l -0.30,2.12 c -0.48,.2 -0.93,.47 -1.35,.78 l -1.99,-0.8 c -0.18,-0.07 -0.39,0 -0.48,.17 l -1.6,2.76 c -0.10,.17 -0.05,.39 .09,.51 l 1.68,1.32 c -0.03,.25 -0.05,.52 -0.05,.78 0,.26 .02,.52 .05,.78 l -1.68,1.32 c -0.15,.12 -0.19,.33 -0.09,.51 l 1.6,2.76 c .09,.17 .31,.24 .48,.17 l 1.99,-0.8 c .41,.32 .86,.58 1.35,.78 l .30,2.12 c .02,.19 .19,.33 .39,.33 l 3.2,0 c .2,0 .36,-0.14 .39,-0.33 l .30,-2.12 c .48,-0.2 .93,-0.47 1.35,-0.78 l 1.99,.8 c .18,.07 .39,0 .48,-0.17 l 1.6,-2.76 c .09,-0.17 .05,-0.39 -0.09,-0.51 l -1.68,-1.32 0,0 z m -5.94,2.01 c -1.54,0 -2.8,-1.25 -2.8,-2.8 0,-1.54 1.25,-2.8 2.8,-2.8 1.54,0 2.8,1.25 2.8,2.8 0,1.54 -1.25,2.8 -2.8,2.8 l 0,0 z" style="fill: #141414;"></path>
  <g>
    <rect x="19" y="5"></rect>
    <text x="20.2" y="11.7">HD</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при добавлении/удаление одного класса, шестеренка вращалась как сейчас. Единственное,- это заблокировать вращение при открытии страницы?

```
path {transform-origin: 18px 18px; animation: cog1 100ms forwards linear}
.ani path {animation: cog 100ms forwards linear}
@keyframes cog1 {0% {transform:rotate(60deg)} 100% {transform:rotate(0deg)}}
@keyframes cog {0% {transform:rotate(0deg)} 100% {transform:rotate(60deg)}}
```

Данный код, возможно выполнить проще?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно добавить класс по первому нажатию, для чего третьим аргументом можно передать объект со свойством `once: true`. Дальше оба класса `ani` и `ina` меняются местами таким же `toggle`.

```js
const setti = document.querySelector('.setti');

c.addEventListener('click', () => {
  setti.classList.add('ina');
    c.addEventListener('click', () => {
      setti.classList.toggle('ani');
      setti.classList.toggle('ina');
    })
}, {once: true});
```

```css
svg { width: 100px }
path {transform-origin: 18px 18px}

.ina path { animation: cog1 100ms forwards linear}
.ani path {animation: cog 100ms forwards linear}

@keyframes cog1 {0% {transform:rotate(60deg)} 100% {transform:rotate(0deg)}}
@keyframes cog {0% {transform:rotate(0deg)} 100% {transform:rotate(60deg)}}

rect {fill:#ff0000; width:13px; height:9px;}
text {fill: white; font-size: 7px}
```

```html
<div id='c'>КЛИК</div>
<svg class='setti' viewBox="0 0 36 36">
  <path d="m 23.94,18.78 c .03,-0.25 .05,-0.51 .05,-0.78 0,-0.27 -0.02,-0.52 -0.05,-0.78 l 1.68,-1.32 c .15,-0.12 .19,-0.33 .09,-0.51 l -1.6,-2.76 c -0.09,-0.17 -0.31,-0.24 -0.48,-0.17 l -1.99,.8 c -0.41,-0.32 -0.86,-0.58 -1.35,-0.78 l -0.30,-2.12 c -0.02,-0.19 -0.19,-0.33 -0.39,-0.33 l -3.2,0 c -0.2,0 -0.36,.14 -0.39,.33 l -0.30,2.12 c -0.48,.2 -0.93,.47 -1.35,.78 l -1.99,-0.8 c -0.18,-0.07 -0.39,0 -0.48,.17 l -1.6,2.76 c -0.10,.17 -0.05,.39 .09,.51 l 1.68,1.32 c -0.03,.25 -0.05,.52 -0.05,.78 0,.26 .02,.52 .05,.78 l -1.68,1.32 c -0.15,.12 -0.19,.33 -0.09,.51 l 1.6,2.76 c .09,.17 .31,.24 .48,.17 l 1.99,-0.8 c .41,.32 .86,.58 1.35,.78 l .30,2.12 c .02,.19 .19,.33 .39,.33 l 3.2,0 c .2,0 .36,-0.14 .39,-0.33 l .30,-2.12 c .48,-0.2 .93,-0.47 1.35,-0.78 l 1.99,.8 c .18,.07 .39,0 .48,-0.17 l 1.6,-2.76 c .09,-0.17 .05,-0.39 -0.09,-0.51 l -1.68,-1.32 0,0 z m -5.94,2.01 c -1.54,0 -2.8,-1.25 -2.8,-2.8 0,-1.54 1.25,-2.8 2.8,-2.8 1.54,0 2.8,1.25 2.8,2.8 0,1.54 -1.25,2.8 -2.8,2.8 l 0,0 z" style="fill: #141414;"></path>
  <g>
    <rect x="19" y="5"></rect>
    <text x="20.2" y="11.7">HD</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```